# Solution for finding intercept point of two moving objects (XY plane)

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

This problem is limited to 2 dimensions (XY plane) + time.

There are two objects, A and B.

Both objects move in a straight line. Object A has an initial speed and decelerates (constant deceleration). Object B's speed is constant.

Initially, A is at InitialPointA. It has an initial speed InitialSpeedA. It's moving in direction DirectionA. It decelerates at DecelerationA.

Initially, object B is at InitialPointB. It moves at a constant speed of SpeedB.

Need to find the direction object B must travel in order to intercept (hit) object A at the earliest point in time.

Per "amd"'s suggestion, I'm editing/adding the approach I've taken so far:
(Note: DirectionA is a unit vector)

CurrentPointA(t) = ((InitialSpeedA * t - ((DecelerationA * t^2) / 2)) * DirectionA) + InitialPointA

The distance B must travel to intercept A at the current time t is

InterceptDistanceB = length(InitialPointB - CurrentPointA(t))

The distance B travels during time t is simply SpeedB * t

What must be found is the time t where

InterceptDistanceB = SpeedB * t

i.e.,

length(InitialPointB - CurrentPointA(t)) = SpeedB * t

Comment: Does A stop or reverse direction once its speed hits zero?

Comment: A stops when it hits zero.

Comment: You’ve got at least two cases to consider, then: if A comes to a stop before the time it would take B to reach A’s path on a perpendicular course—the minimum possible intercept time—you’ve got a different (and simple) solution than one that hits A while it’s still in motion.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at solving this yourself? If so, edit your question to show your thoughts and efforts. Try solving a simpler case first, such as when $A$ starts in the first quadrant and moves parallel to the $y$-axis. The general case can be transformed into this one.

Comment: Additional information on my approach added to the original post.

Comment: You’re a good part of the way to a solution. You have a quartic equation in $t$ and now have to find a root in the interval $[0,t_{\text{stop}}]$, where $t_{\text{stop}}$ is the time that it takes for the target to come to a stop, i.e., `InitialSpeedA / DecelerationA`. You’ll almost certainly have to approximate this root: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm for a brief survey of methods. If you’re going to approximate a solution anyway, you should be able to find one pretty quickly with a straightforward binary search.